# How to get logo out of twitter widget

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter

I am using the Twitter widget from Twitter itself.
You can download it at http://twitter.com/about/resources/widgets/widget_profile

Now i get this code:

```
<script src="http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js"></script>
<script>
new TWTR.Widget({
  version: 2,
  type: 'profile',
  rpp: 4,
  interval: 6000,
  width: 180,
  height: 320,
  theme: {
    shell: {
      background: '#6e6e6e',
      color: '#ffffff'
    },
    tweets: {
      background: '#fefefe',
      color: '#545454',
      links: '#b05c5c'
    }
  },
  features: {
    scrollbar: false,
    loop: false,
    live: false,
    hashtags: true,
    timestamp: true,
    avatars: false,
    behavior: 'all'
  }
}).render().setUser('SchmidtGlobal').start();
</script>
```

When I embed this in my website I get my logo at the top left side.
Is there any possibility to get this out?

It's refereing to this script:  http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Notice the full documented source is at http://twitter.com/javascripts/widgets/widget.js and you're allowed to modify it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the [full source](http://twitter.com/javascripts/widgets/widget.js) the location of the logo is defined here:

```
var logo = isHttps ? 'https://twitter-widgets.s3.amazonaws.com/i/widget-logo.png' : 'http://widgets.twimg.com/i/widget-logo.png';
```

and embedded in HTML here:

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://twitter.com"><img alt="" src="' + logo + '"></a>
```

So you should just drop that part and you're done.

That said, I wonder if this isn't against the license agreement.

---

**UPDATE:** Above method indeed removes the Twitter logo, as the OP suspected, but it is not that difficult to remove the profile image. A look at the resulting widget (using 'Test Settings') shows me that the image's markup is

```
<a class="twtr-profile-img-anchor" href="http://twitter.com/***" target="_blank">
    <img src="http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/***/***.jpg" class="twtr-profile-img" alt="profile">
</a>
```

so it's just a matter of finding code that sets class `twtr-profile-img-anchor` in the [source code](http://twitter.com/javascripts/widgets/widget.js). And look, it's there:

```
/**
  * @public
  * @param {string}
  * sets the profile image source to display in the widget
  * @return self
  */
setProfileImage: function(url) {
  this._profileImage = url;
  this.byClass('twtr-profile-img', 'img').src = isHttps ? url.replace(httpsImageRegex, httpsImageReplace) : url;
  this.byClass('twtr-profile-img-anchor', 'a').href = 'http://twitter.com/' + this.username;
  return this;
}
```

I highly suspect that removing the line that calls `setProfileImage` will suffice:

```
this.setProfileImage(resp[0].user.profile_image_url);
```

The only thing you'll notice is that the header will now be too far to the right. You'll have to override this CSS rule:

```
.twtr-widget-profile h3, .twtr-widget-profile h4 {
    margin: 0 0 0 40px !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i think you are pointing me to the twitter logo right? What i actualy mean is my own profile picture that i want to get rid off.

Comment: @Justmac: Updated my answer; BTW, we live/work very nearly to each other, I think. And I think there's an error on your webdesign page, as the text is now one large hyperlink. ;-)

Comment: Thanks Marcel! Nice to know you also live/work in Utrecht :-). I Will take a look in a few days. Have to do some other jobs first now.

Answer (score 9):

The easiest way would be to use CSS. Create a CSS document and link it to your web page. In the css paste:

```
.twtr-hd, .twtr-ft{display: none;}
```

This will remove the header and footer. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

find **twtr-hd** in the script, add

```
style="display:none"
```

find **twtr-ft** in the script, add

```
style="display:none"
```

this should do it.

<sub>inspired by the [Queen of Nerds' solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6959954/644450)</sub>